# how to scrape table with DOM and insert to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dom, scrape

I have table in sosmpedpedia.com/harga.php, and i want to get header table one and detail table one, in `<div id="question1"`

when i use this code :

```
$htmlContent = file_get_contents("http://sosmedpedia.com/harga.php");

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($htmlContent);

$Header = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('th');
$Detail = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');

//#Get header name of the table
foreach($Header as $NodeHeader) 
{
    $aDataTableHeaderHTML[] = trim($NodeHeader->textContent);
}
//print_r($aDataTableHeaderHTML); die();

//#Get row data/detail table without header name as key
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
foreach($Detail as $sNodeDetail) 
{
    $aDataTableDetailHTML[$j][] = trim($sNodeDetail->textContent);
    $i = $i + 1;
    $j = $i % count($aDataTableHeaderHTML) == 0 ? $j + 1 : $j;
}
//print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();

//#Get row data/detail table with header name as key and outer array index as row number
for($i = 0; $i < count($aDataTableDetailHTML); $i++)
{
    for($j = 0; $j < count($aDataTableHeaderHTML); $j++)
    {
        $aTempData[$i][$aDataTableHeaderHTML[$j]] = $aDataTableDetailHTML[$i][$j];
    }
}
$aDataTableDetailHTML = $aTempData; unset($aTempData);
print_r($aDataTableDetailHTML); die();
```

my problem is, i get another table, i just need table "Harga Sosmed" in `<div id="question1"`

after i get header and detail table i want to insert result scrape table with DOM to Mysql database.

anyone can help me? please

Comment: I'd suggest using `DOMXPath` to explicitly target the elements you want

Comment: Tip: Instead of using `unset`, make a function that establishes scope.